# Why can't I access a pointer to pointer for a stack array?

Tags: c

Please take a look at the following code. It tries to pass an array as a `char**` to a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void printchar(char **x)
{
    printf("Test: %c\n", (*x)[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char test[256];
    char *test2 = malloc(256);

    test[0] = 'B';
    test2[0] = 'A';

    printchar(&test2);            // works
    printchar((char **) &test);   // crashes because *x in printchar() has an invalid pointer

    free(test2);

    return 0;
}
```

The fact that I can only get it to compile by explicitly casting `&test2` to `char**` already hints that this code is wrong.

Still, I'm wondering what exactly is wrong about it. I can pass a pointer to a pointer to a dynamically allocated array but I can't pass a pointer to a pointer for an array on the stack. Of course, I can easily work-around the problem by first assigning the array to a temporary variable, like so:

```
char test[256];
char *tmp = test;
test[0] = 'B';
printchar(&tmp);
```

Still, can someone explain to me why it doesn't work to cast `char[256]` to `char**` directly?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because `test` is not a pointer.

`&test` gets you a pointer to the array, of type `char (*)[256]`, which is not compatible with `char**` (because an array is not a pointer). This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: But why does the C compiler then allow passing something of type `char (*)[256]` to `char**`?

Comment: @ComFreek I suspect that with max warnings and -Werror, it doesn't allow that.

Comment: @ComFreek: It doesn't really allow it. I have to force the compiler to accept it by explicitly casting it to `char**`. Without that cast, it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 38):

`test` is an array, not a pointer, and `&test` is a pointer to the array. It is not a pointer to a pointer.

You may have been told that an array is a pointer, but this is incorrect. The name of an array is a name of the entire object—all the elements. It is not a pointer to the first element. In most expressions, an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. That is a convenience that is often useful. But there are three exceptions to this rule:

- The array is the operand of `sizeof`.
- The array is the operand of `&`.
- The array is a string literal used to initialize an array.

In `&test`, the array is the operand of `&`, so the automatic conversion does not occur. The result of `&test` is a pointer to an array of 256 `char`, which has type `char (*)[256]`, not `char **`.

To get a pointer to a pointer to `char` from `test`, you would first need to make a pointer to `char`. For example:

```
char *p = test; // Automatic conversion of test to &test[0] occurs.
printchar(&p);  // Passes a pointer to a pointer to char.
```

Another way to think about this is to realize that `test` names the entire object—the whole array of 256 `char`. It does not name a pointer, so, in `&test`, there is no pointer whose address can be taken, so this cannot produce a `char **`. In order to create a `char **`, you must first have a `char *`.

Comment: Is this list of three exceptions exhaustive?

Comment: @Ruslan: Yes, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 3.

Comment: Oh, and in C11 there was also the `_Alignof` operator mentioned in addition to `sizeof` and `&`. I wonder why they removed it...

Comment: @Ruslan: That was removed because it was a mistake. `_Alignof` only accepts a type name as an operand and never accepted an array or any other object as an operand. (I do not know why; it seems syntactically and grammatically it could be like `sizeof`, but it is not.)

Answer (score 6):

The type of `test2` is `char *`. So, the type of `&test2` will be `char **` which is compatible with the type of parameter `x` of `printchar()`.
The type of `test` is `char [256]`. So, the type of `&test` will be `char (*)[256]` which is **not** compatible with the type of parameter `x` of `printchar()`.

Let me show you the difference in terms of addresses of `test` and `test2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void printchar(char **x)
{
    printf("x = %p\n", (void*)x);
    printf("*x  = %p\n", (void*)(*x));
    printf("Test: %c\n", (*x)[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char test[256];
    char *test2 = malloc(256);

    test[0] = 'B';
    test2[0] = 'A';

    printf ("test2 : %p\n", (void*)test2);
    printf ("&test2 : %p\n", (void*)&test2);
    printf ("&test2[0] : %p\n", (void*)&test2[0]);
    printchar(&test2);            // works

    printf ("\n");
    printf ("test : %p\n", (void*)test);
    printf ("&test : %p\n", (void*)&test);
    printf ("&test[0] : %p\n", (void*)&test[0]);

    // Commenting below statement
    //printchar((char **) &test);   // crashes because *x in printchar() has an invalid pointer

    free(test2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
test2 : 0x7fe974c02970
&test2 : 0x7ffee82eb9e8
&test2[0] : 0x7fe974c02970
x = 0x7ffee82eb9e8
*x  = 0x7fe974c02970
Test: A

test : 0x7ffee82eba00
&test : 0x7ffee82eba00
&test[0] : 0x7ffee82eba00
```

Point to note here:

The output (memory address) of `test2` and `&test2[0]` is **numerically** same and their type is also same which is `char *`.
But the `test2` and `&test2` are different addresses and their type is also different.
The type of `test2` is `char *`.
The type of `&test2` is `char **`.

```
x = &test2
*x = test2
(*x)[0] = test2[0]
```

The output (memory address) of `test`, `&test` and `&test[0]` is **numerically** same **but their type is different**.
The type of `test` is `char [256]`.
The type of `&test` is `char (*) [256]`.
The type of `&test[0]` is `char *`.

As the output shows `&test` is same as `&test[0]`.

```
x = &test[0]
*x = test[0]       //first element of test array which is 'B'
(*x)[0] = ('B')[0]   // Not a valid statement
```

Hence you are getting segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access a pointer to a pointer because `&test` is not a pointer—it's an array.

If you take the address of an array, cast the array and the address of the array to `(void *)`, and compare them, they will (barring possible pointer pedantry) be equivalent.

What you're really doing is similar to this (again, barring strict aliasing):

```
putchar(**(char **)test);
```

which is quite obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your code expects the argument `x` of `printchar` to point to memory that contains a `(char *)`.

In the first call, it points to the storage used for `test2` and is thus indeed a value that points to a `(char *)`, the latter pointing to the allocated memory.

In the second call, however, there is no place where any such `(char *)` value might be stored and so it is impossible to point to such memory. The cast to `(char **)` you added would have removed a compilation error (about converting `(char *)` to `(char **)`) but it would not make storage appear out of thin air to contain a `(char *)` initialized to point to the first characters of test. Pointer casting in C does not change the actual value of the pointer.

In order to get what you want, you have to do it explicitly:

```
char *tempptr = &temp;
printchar(&tempptr);
```

I assume your example is a distillation of a much larger piece of code; as an example, perhaps you want `printchar` to increment the `(char *)` value that the passed `x` value points to so that on the next call the next character is printed. If that isn't the case, why don't you just pass a `(char *)` pointing to the character to be printed, or even just pass the character itself?

Comment: Good answer; I agree the easiest way to keep this straight is to think about whether or not there's a C object that holds the address of the array, i.e. a pointer object that you can take the address of to get a `char **`.  Array variables/objects simply *are* the array, with the address being implicit, not stored anywhere.  No extra level of indirection to access them, unlike with a pointer variable that points to other storage.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, taking the address of `test` is the same as taking the address of `test[0]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void printchar(char **x)
{
    printf("[printchar] Address of pointer to pointer: %p\n", (void *)x);
    printf("[printchar] Address of pointer: %p\n", (void *)*x);
    printf("Test: %c\n", **x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char test[256];
    char *test2 = malloc(256);

    printf("[main] Address of test: %p\n", (void *)test);
    printf("[main] Address of the address of test: %p\n", (void *)&test);
    printf("[main] Address of test2: %p\n", (void *)test2);
    printf("[main] Address of the address of test2: %p\n", (void *)&test2);

    test[0] = 'B';
    test2[0] = 'A';

    printchar(&test2);            // works
    printchar(&test);   // crashes because *x in printchar() has an invalid pointer

    free(test2);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile that and run:

```
forcebru$ clang test.c -Wall && ./a.out
test.c:25:15: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[256]' to
      parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    printchar(&test);   // crashes because *x in printchar() has an inva...
              ^~~~~
test.c:4:30: note: passing argument to parameter 'x' here
static void printchar(char **x)
                             ^
1 warning generated.
[main] Address of test: 0x7ffeeed039c0
[main] Address of the address of test: 0x7ffeeed039c0 [THIS IS A PROBLEM]
[main] Address of test2: 0x7fbe20c02aa0
[main] Address of the address of test2: 0x7ffeeed039a8
[printchar] Address of pointer to pointer: 0x7ffeeed039a8
[printchar] Address of pointer: 0x7fbe20c02aa0
Test: A
[printchar] Address of pointer to pointer: 0x7ffeeed039c0
[printchar] Address of pointer: 0x42 [THIS IS THE ASCII CODE OF 'B' in test[0] = 'B';]
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So the ultimate cause of the segmentation fault is that this program will try to dereference the absolute address `0x42` (also known as `'B'`), which your program doesn't have permission to read.

Although with a different compiler/machine the addresses will be different: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLBToQwEL33KyZrdIGs7qaJHkRN1m/whhy6pSyN2JK24CbGb8cpCMKqidoDmb438@Z1GH6@57xtT6TiZZ0JuLEuk/qiuCMzqJQ7jxHrmJMcGi0zqIxUjhfMBP4DUXQIySsBPB2TB4tkTElhm2VGWAs6h0ojKgw4PYTXcFo9qsUKDmH8B4WxLDquexDWIct7tqPfCEEOnplUgQ@Y2fMV9NYxbpJ0sN9hDhUSenmVxp9Y5EEKtyhSlpoHSKPw3LDXn3l1vZXeqL8cP/FrRSGA/SBw9jsF73PWlP6nK523pcNju9lsUhzE8n4ZjxD9wLbL6VC6DRnqYXLWa3jR5sl@l9plYgI3zBbCwk5wVluBPxqkmiSHUDALTCHasNIvZb8Zff/cCBHMnBvhaqNgg@vQtu8), but you'll still get this, for some reason:

```
[main] Address of test: 0x7ffd4891b080
[main] Address of the address of test: 0x7ffd4891b080  [SAME ADDRESS!]
```

But the address that causes the segmentation fault may very well be different:

```
[printchar] Address of pointer to pointer: 0x7ffd4891b080
[printchar] Address of pointer: 0x9c000000942  [WAS 0x42 IN MY CASE]
```

Comment: Taking the address of `test` is not the same as taking the address of `test[0]`. The former has type `char (*)[256]`, and the latter has type `char *`. They are not compatible, and the C standard permits them to have different representations.

Comment: When formatting a pointer with `%p`, it should be converted to `void *` (again for reasons of compatibility and representation).

Comment: `printchar(&test);` may crash for you, but the behavior is not defined by the C standard, and people may observe other behaviors in other circumstances.

Comment: Re “So the ultimate cause of the segmentation fault is that this program will try to dereference the absolute address 0x42 (also known as 'B'), which is probably occupied by the OS.”: If there is a segment fault attempting to read a location, it means nothing is mapped there, not that it is occupied by the OS. (Except there could be something mapped there as, say, execute-only with no read permissions, but that is unlikely.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, `&test == &test[0]` on my machine, so at least it gives _the same address_ (for me) - that's what I meant by "the same". Language-wise these will be of different types, of course. Agree about casting to `(void *)`, will edit

Comment: `&test == &test[0]` violates the constraints in C 2018 6.5.9 2 because the types are not compatible. The C standard requires an implementation to diagnose this violation, and the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard. That means your compiler might produce code evaluating them to be equal, but another compiler might not.

Answer (score -4):

The representation of `char [256]` is implementation dependent. It is must not be the same as `char *`.

Casting `&test` of type `char (*)[256]` to `char **` yields undefined behavior.

With some compilers, it may do what you expect, an on others not.

EDIT:

After testing with gcc 9.2.1, it appears that `printchar((char**)&test)` passes in fact `test` as value cast to `char**`. It is as if the instruction was `printchar((char**)test)`. In the `printchar` function, `x` is a pointer to the first char of the array test, not a double pointer to the first character. A double de-reference `x` result in a segmentation fault because the 8 first bytes of the array do not correspond to a valid address.

I get the exact same behavior and result when compiling the program with clang 9.0.0-2.

This may be considered as a compiler bug, or the result of an undefined behavior whose result might be compiler specific.

Another unexpected behavior is that the code

```
void printchar2(char (*x)[256]) {
    printf("px: %p\n", *x);
    printf("x: %p\n", x);
    printf("c: %c\n", **x);
}
```

The output is

```
px: 0x7ffd92627370
x: 0x7ffd92627370
c: A
```

The weird behavior is that `x` and `*x` have the same value.

This is a compiler thing. I doubt that this is defined by the language.

Comment: Do you mean the representation of `char (*)[256]` is implementation-dependent? The representation of `char [256]` is not relevant in this question—it is just a bunch of bits. But, even if you mean the representation of a pointer to an array is different from the representation of a pointer to a pointer, that also misses the point. Even if they have the same representations, the OP’s code would not work, because the pointer to a pointer can be dereferenced twice, as is done in `printchar`, but the pointer to an array cannot, regardless of the representation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the cast from `char (*)[256]` to `char **` is accepted by the compiler, but does not yield the expected result because a `char [256]` is not the same as a `char *`. I assumed, the encoding is different, otherwise it would yield the expected result.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “expected result.” The only specification in the C standard of what the result should be is that, if the alignment is inadequate for `char **`, the behavior is undefined, and that, otherwise, if the result is converted back to `char (*)[256]`, it compares equal to the original pointer. By “expected result”, you might mean that, if `(char **) &test` is further converted to a `char *`, it compares equal to `&test[0]`. That is not an unlikely result in implementations that use a flat address space, but it is not purely a matter of representation.

Comment: Also, “Casting &test of type char (*)[256] to char ** yields undefined behavior.” is not correct. C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 allows a pointer to an object type to be converted to any other pointer to an object type. If the pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type (the referenced type of `char **` is `char *`), then the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, the conversion is defined, although the value is only partially defined, per my comment above.

Comment: `char (*x)[256]` is not the same thing as `char **x`.  The reason `x` and `*x` print the same pointer value is that `x` is simply a pointer to the array.  **Your `*x` *is the array*, and using it in a pointer context decays back to the address of the array**.  No compiler bug there (or in what `(char **)&test` does), just a little mental gymnastics required to figure out that's going on with types.  (cdecl explains it as "declare x as pointer to array 256 of char").  Even using `char*` to access the object-representation of a `char**` isn't UB; it can alias anything.